# Inequality $\frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x), \forall x>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x), \forall x>0$. I wrote it as $e^x < 1 + x + (1+x)^x$ to see if it would make it any simpler. I do not think induction would work since that only works for natural numbers (right?). I also tried writing it as $1 + x + (1+x)^x - e^x > 0$, showing that for a small $x$, the expression would always be positive, and since $x, e^x$, and $(1+x)^x$ are strictly increasing for $x>0$, the expression would always stay positive. But I do not know what $x$ to use for this situation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you get $e^x<1+x+(1+x)^x$? Seems like a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Looking back at it, it seems like it should be $e^x < (x+1)^{x+1}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 5):

Multiply through by $1+x$ and differentiate both sides. On the left, you get $1,$ on the right you get $1 + \log (1+x)>1.$ Since the two sides are equal at $0,$ you are done.

Comment: So if the the inequality holds true for their derivatives, it must hold true for them, as well? Also, would taking the limit as x approaches 0 of the expression work, too?

Comment: If two functions are equal at a point, and the derivative of one is greater than the derivative of the other, the first function is greater than the second to the right of the point... Limit is not enough, you need the inequality everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see then. Thank you for that.

Comment: @AnthonyT : Those are important points mentioned by Igor, without them it is false http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591636/is-fxgx-iff-frac-operatorname-d-operatorname-d-x-fx-frac-opera/591642?noredirect=1#591642

Comment: +1, made me realise something!

Comment: Good counterexample provided, thank you for asking that.

Answer (score 5):

Equivalently you want to prove that $\dfrac{t-1}{t}=1-\dfrac 1 t < \log t, \forall t>1$

But when $t\geqslant 1$ $$\log t =\int_1^t \frac{dy}y\geqslant \int_1^t \frac{dy}{y^2}=1-\frac 1 t$$ with equality only at $t=1$.

Comment: I did not think to rewrite it in terms of another variable, but it works! Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(1+x) > 0$ ($x > 0$), you can multiply both sides by $(1+x)$:
$$\frac{x}{1+x} < \log(1+x) \Rightarrow x < (1+x)\log(1+x)$$
After, you can apply exponential function to both sides:
$$x < (1+x)\log(1+x) \Rightarrow e^x < e^{1+x}(1+x) \Rightarrow e^x < ee^x(1+x)$$
You can simplify $e^x$ from both sides, since $e^x > 0$, and then you get that:
$$1 < e(1+x)$$
Then:

$$ex + e - 1 > 0 \Rightarrow x + 1 - \frac{1}{e} > 0 \Rightarrow x > \frac{1}{e} - 1$$

Since, $\frac{1}{e} - 1 < 0$ and $x > 0$, then you have the proof you want!

Comment: Very nice! I did not see such an algebraic manipulation when I looked over it myself, but this does indeed work! Thank you for that.

Comment: At a first glance, it looked really hard to me... anyway, I gave it a try and I found this way to solve it :D

Comment: $e^x < e^{1+x}(1+x) = e^x < ee^x(1+x)$???

Comment: @medicu Sorry, it was $e^x < e^{1+x}(1+x) \Rightarrow e^x < ee^x(1+x)$. I corrected it.

Comment: Applying the exponential to both sides:
$$
x\lt(1+x)\log(1+x)\Rightarrow e^x\lt(1+x)^{1+x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)$. Then $f'(x)=-\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$, hence $f$ is stricly decreasing. Now $f(0)=0$.

This shows that the inequality holds if $x>-1$, equality is achieved only in $x=0$.

Comment: $f$ is only strictly decreasing for $x>0$. So the implication in your final sentence that the inequality fails for $x\in(-1,0)$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the (well-known?) inequality $1+u\le e^u$ for all $u$, let $u=-\log(x)$:
$$
\begin{align}
1+u&\le e^u\\
1-\log(x)&\le\frac1x\\
\frac{x}{1+x}&\le\log(x)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $\mathbb{ln}(1+x) = \int_{1}^{1+x}\frac{1}{t}dt$ we know that $\mathbb{ln}(1+x)$ is just the area under the curve $\frac{1}{t}$ between $1$ and $1+x$.

Since $\frac{1}{t}$ is strictly decreasing we know that it reaches its minimum at $1+x$ on this interval.  The interval also has length $(1+x)-1=x$ and so the area under the curve is strictly greater than the area of the rectangle having height $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and width $x$.